# Unpacking values from a python 3 `product` iterator built from `zip` iterators

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

I am converting some code from Python 2 to Python 3. I ran into an issue where some Python 2 builtins used to generate lists, but now generate iterators in Python 3. I wanted to rewrite this code but have not found a way make the program work without converting the iterators to lists, which does not seem very efficient. The question is whether there is a way to make this code work using iterators instead of converting the iterators to lists?

Here is a simplified version of the Python 3 program.

```
 from itertools import product

 points = {(1, 1), (0.5, 0.5), (0.75, 0.75)}
 labels = range(len(points))

 zips = zip(points, labels)
 for pair in product(zips,zips):
     if pair[0][1] != pair[1][1]:
         print("good")
```

Note, I simplified the `for` loop to just print "good." The real program calculates Euclidean distance, but "good" preserves the basic idea.

Further note that in Python 3, the `zip` and `range` builtins generate and iterators. Then the `product` function from `itertools` creates an iterator based upon `zip` and `range` iterators.

When I run this code in Python 3, The loop just ends without ever printing  "good," which is not accurate. The code seems to just bypass the loop since I don't think it finds any values in `pair`.

The solution that I found was to just convert the variable `zips` to a list. So the code looks like.

```
 from itertools import product

 points = {(1, 1), (0.5, 0.5), (0.75, 0.75)}
 labels = range(len(points))

 zips = list(zip(points, labels))
 for pair in product(zips,zips):
     if pair[0][1] != pair[1][1]:
         print("good")
```

In the modified code things work, but I have lost the nice iterator structure.

So again, the question is whether I can rewrite this code without having to convert the iterators to lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing `zips` to `product` twice, use the `repeat` argument:

```
for pair in product(zip(points, labels), repeat=2):
    ...
```

Note that `product` will materialize the iterator under the hood anyway. It has to, since it needs to iterate over the elements more than once.

Comment: Oh this is great. This worked just fine. Hmm, do you know what the code did not work when I used `product(zips, zips)` ? Seems like I am missing why this updated code works.

Comment: @krishnab: With `product(zips, zips)`, `product` thinks the arguments are independent and gets mixed up when advancing one iterator advances the other. With `repeat`, it knows to only materialize the iterator once.

Comment: Ah okay. Now I get it. Thanks so much for your help.